Magento 2.4.7 the additional column in ordered items table in admin not showing
Magento 2.4.7 the additional column in ordered items table in admin not showing
I have already tried the extend the sales_order_view.xml  but still not working. Reference file path is
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

And
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_items">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="product_image" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Image</item>
                        <item name="renderer" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\ProductImage</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>

It gives 1 exception(s):

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Array to string conversion in
/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/items.phtml
on line 20

Can any one help me short out this issue .

its seems PHP error, please check following https://www.sourcecodester.com/article/16555/how-fix-php-warning-array-string-conversion-error-php.html


    
        
            
                
                    
                        Product Image
                        Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\ProductImage
                        10
                    
                
            
        
    

